# If $M$ is an oriented manifold with boundary, then this induces an orientation on $\partial M$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Setup: Let $M^n$ be an *oriented* smooth manifold with boundary. We want to show that this induces an orientation on $\partial M$.

*Proof*:

Let $\mathcal{A} := \{(U_i,\varphi_i):i \in I\}$ be an atlas of $M$ and $$\mathcal{A}_{\partial M} := \{(V_i,\psi_i):i \in I\} := \{(U_i \cap \partial M,\varphi_i|_{U_i \cap \partial M}): i \in I\}$$ be the induced atlas on $\partial M$.

For $$x = (0,x') \in \varphi_i(U_i \cap U_j \cap \partial M) = \varphi_i(U_i \cap U_j) \cap \partial \mathbb{R}^n\_ = \psi_i(U_i \cap U_j)$$ we have $$det\Big(D(\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})\Big)\Big|_x > 0$$ by another theorem, since $M$ is orientable is equivalent to this condition.

Now, we have that $$(\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})^1(x) = (\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})^1 (0,x') = 0 \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Here is where I get lost. In the notes I have, it says that $$\frac{\partial (\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i)^1}{\partial x^k}(x) = 0$$ for $k \geq 2$, which seems right, since the value is constantly $0$ on the domain. *But*, then it says that we have $$(\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})^1(x+te_1) < 0, \ t < 0$$ and that this implies that $$\frac{\partial (\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})^1}{\partial x^1}> 0.$$ Why do we have this implication?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the first component?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I´ll change that :)

Comment: Just write $f(t)$ for that function. Then $f$ is defined for sufficiently small $t\leq 0$, with $f(t)<0$ if $t<0$ and $f(0)=0$. So from this limited information you can deduce that $f’(0)\geq 0$ (draw a picture for intuition). For the rigorous proof, simply write out the difference quotient and be careful with signs. This is just a basic calculus lemma. Now for your case, notice that by definition $f’(0)$ is the first partial derivative. Finally, why must the derivative be non-zero?

Comment: I suppose you just mean that you get a negative denominator and numerator in the difference quotient $$\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(t-h)-f(0)}{h}$$ hence a positive value for each fixed $h$, atleast, although the limit could be $0$. Why not positive, hm, oh, I see, maybe because the derivatives have to be continuous, since $f$ is smooth? I seem to be to tired to think right now.

Comment: Ummm it should be $f(0+h)$. And no, single-variable calculus only tells you $\geq 0$ regardless of how smooth $f$ is (eg $f(t)=-t^2$). To get $>0$, you need to use all the information, particularly you’re dealing with charts… why would they make the previous remark about the other partials?

Comment: Yes, clearly I can´t think straight, it should be as you say. The remark about the other partials is because it is relevant for the overall theorem, I skipped some details that were not relevant for my confusion.

Comment: That was a rhetorical question.

Comment: Well, if $f'(0) = 0$, then by basic linear algebra, the determinant of the jacobian, $$det\Big(D(\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})\Big)\Big|_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1} \cdot det \Big(D(\psi_j \circ \psi_i^{-1})\Big|_{x'}\Big) = 0,$$ contrary to our assumption that it is strictly positive, since $M$ is orientable. 

$f = (\varphi_j \circ \varphi_i^{-1})$ here.

Comment: Right, or simply contrary to the fact that chart transitions are diffeomorphisms so the determinant is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo. This clarified things. I actually meant "why not negative" above, regarding the derivative. But I reminded myself of Rudin:s definition, and I think I see why not. Then we will have an $|q| = \epsilon > 0$ so that we can not find any $\delta > 0$ so that if $0 < d(t,0) < \delta \implies d(\phi(t),q) < q$, where $q < 0$, assuming that $$\phi(t) = \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{f(t)}$$ and $$f'(x)_{-} = \lim_{t \to 0^-} \phi(t) = q.$$

$d(p,q) = |p-q|$ here.